# telegram get channel name by channel id

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

i'm using TLsharp as a telegram API,
in GetHistory function if the message forward from another channels it will be contains of :
fwd_from_channel_id
fwd_from_channel_post
fwd_from_date
my question is how can I obtain the channel name from channel id?

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about a chat with [getChat](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchat) method in bot API,accepts both integer *chat_id* or channels *@username*,retruns a [Chat Object](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat) on success, that contains a filed named *title*.

i don't know if TLsharp have this method or not but it shouldn't be hard to add custom methods

Comment: getchat function response is CHANNEL_ID Invalid
and after i resolve the channel id again using the channel name this function works!
it seems like some security policy

Comment: yes its true,you have to make your request with *@channelname* for first time,then your bot can getChat info with channel_id afterward,but **BEWARE** its not permanent,you will lose your permission to get channel info with channel integer id after a certain time (72hr i think),so actually channel integer id is useful when your bot is member/admin in that channel or the method returns chat not found after a time period,BTW consider accept as answer if that helped you :)     @user3033531